# Banding on ICS Holo Theme

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm seeing banding on my activities using the Holo theme on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Android version 4.0.2.

Below is a screenshot of my PreferenceActivity, taken from the Nexus using DDMS, which illustrates the issue.

I have tried adding (to no avail):

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
```

What causes this and is there a work around?

[image: PreferenceActivity]

Comment: Did you find any resolution for this? I'm experiencing banding issues when applying a gradient in various `View` classes, even though I'm already applying various known fixes (such as `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888`). It seems to be an issue that only occurs on my 4.0 and 4.1 devices.

Comment: Does this occur on an actual device or just the emulator?

For me the emulator does this however my devices do not.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {

            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Comment: Does not help for me... has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Dither itself is an imperfect solution to the problem, check to see that:

1. Make sure the Bitmap is loaded with the following settings `BitmapFactory.Options.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGBA_8888` and `BitmapFactory.Options.inDither=false`
2. The background image is not stretched

[Reference](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/)

Comment: I'm not loading bitmaps. Its the default ICS gradient background.